# SQL Server 2008, how to get value of a certain column where another column changed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to add a field called "change date" which I indicated in the table. I have the table already with the other three columns. It is shown below but I want to get the date of the last change for each contract. Would this involve some kind of loop? I am not sure where to start here. The dates are just examples, it could be anywhere from 2007 to current. Thanks for the help.

```
Date Contract Status Change Date
9/30/2015 1 A 6/30/2015
8/31/2015 1 A 6/30/2015
7/31/2015 1 A 6/30/2015
6/30/2015 1 A 6/30/2015
9/30/2015 2 D 8/31/2015
8/31/2015 2 D 8/31/2015
7/31/2015 2 A 6/30/2015
6/30/2015 2 A 6/30/2015
9/30/2015 3 D 9/30/2015
8/31/2015 3 E 8/31/2015
7/31/2015 3 A 6/30/2015
6/30/2015 3 A 6/30/2015
```

Answer (score 2):

You can seemingly do this with a window function:

```
select t.*, min(date) over (partition by contract, status) as change_date
from t;
```

But the problem is a bit trickier.  You want the earliest date from the most recent group of similar statuses.  One method is to identify the groups using a difference of window functions.  Then calculate the minimum within each group and then the maximum of that value:

```
select t.*,
       max(group_change_date) over (partition by contract, status) as change_date
from (select t.*,
             min(date) over (partition by contract, status) as group_change_date
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by contract order by date) as seqnum_cd,
                   row_number() over (partition by contract, status order by date) as seqnum_cds,
            from t
           ) t
      ) t;
```

Comment: @DhruvJoshi . . . I misunderstood the question and revised the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` like this:

```
select MAX([Date]), contract from tbl GROUP BY conrtact
```

Result:

```
Date      | Contract 
===================
9/30/2015 | 1
9/30/2015 | 2
9/30/2015 | 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the window function max() over

**Example**

```
Select [Date]
      ,[Contract]
      ,[Status]
      ,[Change Date] = max([Date]) over (Partition By [Contract])
 from YourTable
```

**Returns**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You Can achieve this using Windows Aggregate Functions.

Below is the query that will return your desired result.

```
 select  Date_Contract,
    contract,
    status, 
    min(date_Contract) over(partition by contract, status) 
    from table1;
```

[DEMO](http://rextester.com/TMGJ24045)